# How to use sed command to replace folder path names in linux?

Tags: bash, sed

How to replace folder path using following command,

```
sed -i "s/# pidfile: '/var/run/jboss-eap/jboss-eap.pid /# pidfile: '/var/run/jboss-eap/jboss-eap-aa.pid' /g" ks

Error:  sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'
```

When I use `sed -i "s/sample/hi/g" sam.txt` It working fine , but above mentioned expression throws unknown exception. How to resolve this error ? have any idea ?

Comment: What is your original text and the text to be replaced? It is not clear this way

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the delimiter (`/`) in your statement, as it is also in your pattern.

```
sed -i "s@# pidfile: '/var/run/jboss-eap/jboss-eap.pid @# pidfile: '/var/run/jboss-eap/jboss-eap-aa.pid' @g" ks
```

Here I replaced it wiht `@`, but you can use any delimiter, as long as it's not part of the pattern text.