# Sed search replace a pattern in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

```
#!/bin/bash 
work_dir=`pwd`

syn_file="$work_dir/di/aon_lint/dc/run_syn"

sed -i 's/setenv workspace.*/setenv workspace $work_dir/g' ${syn_file}
```

current code: `setenv workspace /path/a/b/c`

needed :      `setenv workspace /path/updated`          which is `$work_dir`

result from script : `setenv workspace $work_dir`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- using double quotes (`"`) in place of single
- replace separator with a character that's not the slash `/` (I used `:`)
- use `-e` option (not sure about this, but it works on my Mac)

in the sed command:

```
sed -i -e "s:setenv workspace.*:setenv workspace $work_dir:g" ${syn_file}
```

Explanation: by using a different delimiter than the slash in `sed`, the slash can be used as a literal character and so you can enter the path as it is without having to escape the slashes. Link: [delimiter in sed substitution can be any other single character](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).

Alternatively, with slash escaping:

```
escaped_work_dir=$(echo "$work_dir" | sed 's%/%\\/%g')
sed -i -e "s/setenv workspace.*/setenv workspace $escaped_work_dir/g" ${syn_file}
```

Related questions: [How to use sed command to replace folder path names in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788352/how-to-use-sed-command-to-replace-folder-path-names-in-linux), [How to replace a path with another path in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061410/how-to-replace-a-path-with-another-path-in-sed), [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

work_dir=$(pwd)
syn_file="$work_dir/di/aon_lint/dc/run_syn"

sed -i "s|\(setenv workspace \).*|\1$work_dir|g" "${syn_file}"
```

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks.